# Unable to launch meteor - npm peer requirements react-router@3.0.0 installted, react-router@2.x needed

Tags: meteor, react-router, telescope

I'm new at coding and trying to use `Telescope` for a project.
In order to do this, I need `Meteor` and `React` but I'm stuck at launching `Meteor`: it looks like my version of react-router is too new...

Here is what I did :

• I have installed `Meteor`

• I have installed the latest version of `Meteor` using `meteor update –patch`

• I have cloned `Telescope`

• I have installed react-dom using `meteor npm install-save react-dom`

• I have installed react-router using `meteor npm install –save react-router`

• Since I had an issue, I added react to the meteor directory using `meteor add reactrouter:react-router`, which returned me
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AjSS.png)

BUT when I try to launch `Meteor`, I have this error :

> WARNING: npm peer requirements (for reactrouter:react-router-ssr) not installed:
>   W20161125-19:23:36.790(1)? (STDERR)  - react-router@3.0.0 installed, react-router@2.x needed

Complete picture of the terminal can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQvwP.png).

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? How can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: This may not be of much help but referring themeteorchef.com might help.

Comment: Why did you install `react-dom` directly? Why not simply clone, issue `meteor npm i` and when all of the dpes are installed, run `meteor` (that's also what the Telescope instructions say)?

Comment: A warning cannot prevent you from launching the app. It looks like the actual problem is that you didn't do `meteor npm install`, like MasterAM said.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. MasterAM was right. I don't know why I just didn't follow the instructions, it works perfectly. Thank you!